# How to identify the storage class in Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Suppose I have media assets stored in **S3 Standard Storage**. After 30 days it moved to **S3 Standard-Infrequent Access Storage** and after 90 days it is moved to Glacier by lifecycle policies that I configured.

So at any point of time how can I identify where the object is stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Storage Class** of an object indicates where the data is "stored".

For **Standard** and **Standard-Infrequent Access (Standard-IA)**, the object is kept as normal in Amazon S3.

For **Glacier**, the object is still *listed* within Amazon S3 (including name, size, metadata, etc) but the *content* of the object is stored in Glacier.

The storage class can be determined via the Management Console, API call or [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), eg:

```
$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket

 {
    "Contents": [
        {
            "LastModified": "2014-06-19T00:30:49.000Z", 
            "ETag": "\"c963435563f7e3e6b143b50ff9c68168\"", 
            "StorageClass": "GLACIER", 
            "Key": "foo.jpg", 
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "fred", 
                "ID": "1de5d80077bd70578d092d9b450b0c916c2c79d1d2b550e5a99a4d21ddb1ab1a"
            }, 
            "Size": 15091
        }
    ]
}
```

See:

- Amazon S3 documentation: [Storage Classes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer but i wanted to access/update object "foo.jpg", will it return me with GET api call directly, or first I have to locate the storage class and then depending upon the storage class I have to call the api and access it? Mine is media encoding and distribution application where daily 200-300 media files come and I have to store that in S3. So at nay point of time in future I may need it for any purpose. You can not always list the bucket with thousands of objects to identify a particular object.

Comment: Objects in **Standard, Standard-IA and Reduced Redundancy** can be retrieved immediately via a normal GET request. Objects in **Glacier** cannot be retrieved since their contents are not in S3. You would need to [initiate a restore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOSTrestore.html) of the object from Glacier and it will only be available for retrieval after 3-5 hours. **Objects can be replaced** (upload with same name) regardless of storage class, but will start as **Standard** storage.